# Javascript carosel animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an image carousel with center animation. I don't want to use CSS animations, instead I'd like to use jQuery.

By pressing the 'Prev' button the animation will start. One of the slides which will be central begins to grow. I've used jQuery's `animate()` to animate width and height. Everything works as required except I can't understand why the animation makes the central slide jump.

I have created this sample. If you push the 'Prev' button the animation will start.

```js
var scroll_speed = 4000;
var items_cnt = $('.mg_item').length;
var container_size = $(".main_cnt").innerWidth();
var item_avg_w = container_size / 5;
var item_center_w = ((item_avg_w / 100) * 20) + item_avg_w;
var item_center_h = (item_center_w / 16) * 9 + 30;
var item_w = ((container_size - item_center_w) / 4) - 2;
var item_h = ((item_w / 16) * 9);
var gallery_content = $('.gallery_body').html();
$('.gallery_body').html(gallery_content + gallery_content + gallery_content);
var items_offset = items_cnt * item_w + 14;

$('.gallery_body').css('left', -items_offset);
$('.mg_item').css("width", item_w);
$('.mg_item').css("height", item_h);

//$('.mg_item').css("margin-bottom", (item_center_h - item_h) / 2);
//$('.mg_item').css("margin-top", (item_center_h - item_h) / 2);
//$('.mg_item_с').css("width", item_center_w);
//$('.mg_item_с').css("height", item_center_h);
//document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--center_width', item_center_w + "px");
//document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--center_height', item_center_h + "px");

$('.main_cnt').css("height", item_center_h);
check_visible();
AssignCenter(0);

function gonext() {
  AssignCenter(-1);
  ZoomIn();
  $('.gallery_body').animate({
    left: '+=' + (item_w + 2),
  }, scroll_speed, "linear", function() {
    LoopSlides();
  });
}

function goprev() {
  AssignCenter(1);
  ZoomIn();
  $('.gallery_body').animate({
    left: '-=' + (item_w + 2),
  }, scroll_speed, "linear", function() {
    LoopSlides();
  });
}

function ZoomIn() {
  $('.center').animate({
    width: item_center_w + 'px',
    height: item_center_h + 'px',
  }, scroll_speed, function() {});
}

function LoopSlides() {
  var cur_pos = $('.gallery_body').position().left
  var left_margin = Math.abs(items_offset * 2 - item_w) * -1;
  var right_margin = 0 - item_w;
  if (cur_pos < left_margin) {
    $('.gallery_body').css('left', -items_offset);
  }
  if (cur_pos >= 0) {
    $('.gallery_body').css('left', -items_offset);

  }
  check_visible();
  AssignCenter(0);
}

function check_visible() {
  $('.mg_item').each(function(i, obj) {
    var pos = $(this).offset().left;
    if (pos < 0 || pos > container_size) {
      $(this).addClass("invisible");
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).removeClass("invisible");
    }
  });
}

function AssignCenter(offset) {
  var center_slide = $('.active')[2 + offset];
  $('.center').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).removeClass("center");
  });
  $(center_slide).addClass("center");
  //$(center_slide).css("width", item_center_w);
  //$(center_slide).css("height", item_center_h);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --center_width: 0px;
  --center_height: 0px;
}

.main_cnt {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.gallery_body {
  width: 500%;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  position: relative;
}

.mg_item {
  width: 198px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 120px;
}

.center {
  background-color: brown;
  /*width: var(--center_width) !important;
            height: var(--center_height) !important;*/
}

.item_c {
  width: 410px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 120px;
}

.video-js .vjs-dock-text {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="main_cnt">
  <div class="gallery_body">
    <div class="mg_item">1</div>
    <div class="mg_item">2</div>
    <div class="mg_item">3</div>
    <div class="mg_item">4</div>
    <div class="mg_item">5</div>
    <div class="mg_item">6</div>
    <div class="mg_item">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<button onclick="gonext()">GONEXT</button>
<button onclick="goprev()">GOPREV</button>
<button onclick="check_visible()">CHEVIS</button>
```